# Save Postgres Data to Directory in Docker Named Volume

Tags: postgresql, docker

**Problem**

I have an application with postgres.  I want to be able to back up the initial database data so that I don't have to re enter it each deployment.  However, despite having a named volume set up in my compose file.

What I'm not sure of is how to have postgres save its data into the directory associated with the volume.  I'm also not sure exactly how to associate a directory with the named volume. What I want is for the docker host server to be able to see the postgress data in the named volume's associated directory.

Could someone please provide an explanation/some examples of how to handle this?  Right now even though the volume is associated with the docker service in the compose file, it doesn't write any data to the database_volume/ directory.  This is what I would like to address.

**Code**

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

ARG requirements=requirements/production.txt
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sasite.settings.production_test

WORKDIR /app

COPY manage.py /app/
COPY requirements/ /app/requirements/ 

RUN pip install -r $requirements

COPY config config
COPY sasite sasite
COPY templates templates
COPY logs logs

ADD /scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x /docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 8001

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "--config", "config/gunicorn.conf", "--log-config", "config/logging.conf", "-e", "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sasite.settings.production_test", "-w", "4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8001", "sasite.wsgi:application"]
```

And my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  app:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prodtest
      args:
        requirements: requirements/production.txt
    container_name: dj01
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sasite.settings.production_test
      - PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /static:/static
      - /media:/media
    networks:
      - main
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:10.1-alpine
    container_name: ps01
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: sasite_db
      POSTGRES_USER: pguser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pguser123
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - database_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - main
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx
    container_name: ng01
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx-prodtest.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./static:/usr/share/nginx/sasite/static
      - ./media:/usr/share/nginx/sasite/media
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - main
    depends_on:
      - app

networks:
  main:

volumes:
  database_volume:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ./database_volume
      o: bind
```